# What add-ons are creating messages in ExpressionEngine Dev Log?

Tags: expressionengine

Is there a way to know which add-ons are creating messages in the Developer Log in the EE control panel or is it basically a process of elimination?

Example messages:

1. A third-party add-on is calling $this->load->library('security'),
   which is deprecated as the CI_Security class has been moved to Core,
   so it is always loaded.
2. The system has detected an add-on that is using outdated code that
   may stop working or cause issues with the system.  Deprecated
   function login_form() called in on line 0.

Comment: I've seen that one a couple of times myself and was wondering the same thing.

Comment: For what it's worth, Tad, my money is on it being a Solspace addon. A quick search in Sublime for one of my recent projects reveals 4 addons using load->library('security').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. This message will likely be removed in a future release. It's causing too much confusion than help and isn't entirely necessary. Yes it would be helpful for the developer log to let you know which addon is causing the problem, but the logistics of parsing backtraces to find that information proves to be difficult. Which brings us on to message #2:
2. As GDmac said, it's best to search your project for any calls to login_form() in the CP controller. Normally a file and line number would be provided in this kind of message, but as I said, parsing backtrace info doesn't always work.

We'll continue to try to make this better. The deprecation warnings have been working great for the most part, but occasionally messages like these pop up it can be difficult to know what to do about them.

Comment: Since it's a *developer* log, maybe you could just dump the backtrace as well, so advanced users can easily find the culprit?

Comment: Not a bad idea, Adrian. Since trying to make a pretty sentence out of it doesn't always work, maybe we can add another parameter to that log function to include a full backtrace instead. We'll play around with that idea and I'll bring it up with the others to see what they think. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome. Probably best if you just always store the backtrace, then optionally show it using some sort of "more info" button in the CP.

Comment: Kevin, as a quick addition, instead of backtrace tracking, wouldn't it be possible to do some basic checklist? logging the url (minus the session_id), should cover module/extension settings pages, an action_id also makes the add_on name discoverable, if a hook has been called there's probably also a means to discover the current running extension. (but maybe quite tedious to make conclusive)

Answer (score 0):

A decent text-editor can search thru your third-party directory and
look for a line containing `load->library('security')`

Comment: Agreed, but having the error message telling you which one would be so much more useful,